# Compiling apib undefined reference to symbol 'pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5'

Tags: compiling, gcc, make, glibc

I want to compile [apib](https://code.google.com/p/apib/) on my ubuntu 13.04 box but I am having issues with pthread lib. This is the error that I get :

```
$ colormake -j 5
cd src && make all
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/monkey/bin/apib-1_0/src'
gcc -std=gnu99 -pedantic -Wall -Wno-deprecated-declarations -g -O2 -I. -I/usr/include/apr-1.0 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -D_GNU_SOURCE   -c -o apib_cpu.o apib_cpu.c
gcc -std=gnu99 -pedantic -Wall -Wno-deprecated-declarations -g -O2 -I. -I/usr/include/apr-1.0 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -D_GNU_SOURCE   -c -o apib_iothread.o apib_iothread.c
gcc -std=gnu99 -pedantic -Wall -Wno-deprecated-declarations -g -O2 -I. -I/usr/include/apr-1.0 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -D_GNU_SOURCE   -c -o apib_lines.o apib_lines.c
gcc -std=gnu99 -pedantic -Wall -Wno-deprecated-declarations -g -O2 -I. -I/usr/include/apr-1.0 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -D_GNU_SOURCE   -c -o apib_main.o apib_main.c
gcc -std=gnu99 -pedantic -Wall -Wno-deprecated-declarations -g -O2 -I. -I/usr/include/apr-1.0 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -D_GNU_SOURCE   -c -o apib_oauth.o apib_oauth.c
gcc -std=gnu99 -pedantic -Wall -Wno-deprecated-declarations -g -O2 -I. -I/usr/include/apr-1.0 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -D_GNU_SOURCE   -c -o apib_reporting.o apib_reporting.c
gcc -std=gnu99 -pedantic -Wall -Wno-deprecated-declarations -g -O2 -I. -I/usr/include/apr-1.0 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -D_GNU_SOURCE   -c -o apib_priorityq.o apib_priorityq.c
gcc -std=gnu99 -pedantic -Wall -Wno-deprecated-declarations -g -O2 -I. -I/usr/include/apr-1.0 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -D_GNU_SOURCE   -c -o apib_url.o apib_url.c
gcc -std=gnu99 -pedantic -Wall -Wno-deprecated-declarations -g -O2 -I. -I/usr/include/apr-1.0 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -D_GNU_SOURCE   -c -o apib_mon.o apib_mon.c
gcc -std=gnu99 -pedantic -Wall -Wno-deprecated-declarations -o ../apibmon  apib_mon.o apib_lines.o apib_cpu.o -lapr-1
/usr/bin/ld: apib_mon.o: undefined reference to symbol 'pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
/usr/bin/ld: note: 'pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5' is defined in DSO /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 so try adding it to the linker command line
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [../apibmon] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/monkey/bin/apib-1_0/src'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Whereas all needed libraries are installed:

```
$ dpkg -l  | grep apr && dpkg -l | grep libssl
ii  libapr1                                   1.4.6-3ubuntu1                             amd64        Apache Portable Runtime Library
ii  libapr1-dev                               1.4.6-3ubuntu1                             amd64        Apache Portable Runtime Library - Development Headers
ii  libaprutil1                               1.4.1-3                                    amd64        Apache Portable Runtime Utility Library
ii  libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3                   1.4.1-3                                    amd64        Apache Portable Runtime Utility Library - SQLite3 Driver
ii  libaprutil1-dev                           1.4.1-3                                    amd64        Apache Portable Runtime Utility Library - Development Headers
ii  libaprutil1-ldap                          1.4.1-3                                    amd64        Apache Portable Runtime Utility Library - LDAP Driver
ii  libssl-dev                                1.0.1c-4ubuntu8.1                          amd64        SSL development libraries, header files and documentation
ii  libssl-doc                                1.0.1c-4ubuntu8.1                          all          SSL development documentation documentation
ii  libssl1.0.0:amd64                         1.0.1c-4ubuntu8.1                          amd64        SSL shared libraries
ii  libssl1.0.0:i386                          1.0.1c-4ubuntu8.1                          i386         SSL shared libraries
```

In Makefile :

```
APR_LIBS = -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lm -lcrypto -lpthread -lssl -lapr-1 -laprutil-1
```

Comment: it looks like a spell-checking error, because "could not read symbols" - you could inform the coders at gnu.org resp. at gcc and glibc ?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, I have found it - there was an error in Makefile

`APR_ONLY_LIBS` did not have libthread linked :

```
APR_ONLY_LIBS = -lapr-1
```

So I changed it to :

```
APR_ONLY_LIBS = -lapr-1 -lpthread
```

Answer (score -1):

If you came here cause of an ant build problem, just include pthread.

```
<property name="client.lib.path" value="/usr/local/lib"/> #this filepath
<property name="client.lib.list" value="fltk,pthread,stdc++"/> #this line
<libset dir="${client.lib.path}" libs="${client.lib.list}"/> #variable here with file path mentioned above
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)